# Django fontsize tinymce

Tags: django, tinymce, font-size

I am trying to use django tinymce in my project but the font is too small. I have googled it and learned I am meant to use content_css but without proper step by step approaches as to how exactly this should be done.

I am wondering if there was another way and if there isn't, could someone give me a simple step by step approach to solving it using the content_css.
Below is the forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
text = forms.CharField(help_text='Enter your Post here', widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}))
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial='User')
created_on = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=timezone.now())


class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('title', 'text',)

{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

    {% block body_block %}
    <!-- <h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>
    <form method='post'>
        <textarea id = 'mytextarea'>Hello, World!</textarea>
    </form> -->
    {% if post %}
        <div class="single">
             <div class="container">
                  <div class="col-md-8 single-main">
                      <div class="single-grid">
                            <h4><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></h4>
                            <img src="{% static 'images/post1.jpg' %}" alt=""/>
                            <p>{{ post.text|safe }}</p>
                      </div>
                        <div class="comments">
                            <h2><u>Comments</u></h2>
                                {% if comments %}
                                    {% for comment in comments %}
                                    <h3>~{{ comment.commenter.first_name|title}} {{comment.commenter.last_name|title }}</h3>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                                {{ comment.text|safe }}
                                        </</li><br>
                                    </ul>
                                    <span class="hidden-xs"style="margin-left:70%;, font-family:Arial">Published: {{ comment.created_on }}</span >
                                    {% if comment.commenter == request.user  or user.is_superuser %}
                                            <a href="{% url 'blog:delete_comment' comment.id %}"><button style="margin-left:90%;,line-height: .9;color: red;, font-family:Arial;" type="button" name="button">Delete</button></a>
                                    {% endif %}

                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% else %}
                                    No comments available
                                {% endif %}
                        </div>
                      <div class="content-form">
                             <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
                             {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <form id="comment_form" action="{% url 'blog:detail' post.slug %}" method="post">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                                {{ hidden }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                            {{ field.errors }}

                                            {{ field }}<br/><br/>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                                </form>
                                {% else %}
                                <a href="{% url 'blog:handle_login' %}">You must be logged in to comment</a>
                                {% endif %}
                                 </div>



                         <ul class="comment-list " >
                               <h5 class="post-author_head">Written by <a href="#" title="Posts by admin" rel="author">{{ post.author.first_name|title }}  {{ post.author.last_name|title }}</a></h5>
                               <li><img src="{% static 'images/avatar.png' %}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                               <div class="desc">
                               <p>View all posts by: <a href="#" title="Posts by admin" rel="author">{{ post.author.first_name|title }}  {{ post.author.last_name|title }}</a></p>
                               </div>
                               <div class="clearfix"></div>
                               </li>
                          </ul>
                  </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 side-content">
                        <div class="recent">
                         <h3>RECENT POSTS</h3>
                         {% if recent_posts %}
                         <ul>
                             {% for post in recent_posts %}
                         <li><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' post.slug %}">{{post.title|title }}</a></li>
                         {% endfor %}
                         </ul>
                         {% else %}
                     <li><a href="#">No post has been posted</a></li>
                         {% endif %}
                     </div>
                     <div class="comments">
                         <h3>RECENT COMMENTS</h3>
                         {% if recent_comments %}
                         <ul>
                             {% for comment in recent_comments %}
                         <li><a href="{% url 'blog:detail' comment.post.slug %}">{{comment.commenter|title}} on {{comment.post|title}}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                         </ul>
                         {% else %}
                         <li><a href="#">No comments at the moment</a></li>
                         {% endif %}
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                     <div class="archives">
                         <h3>ARCHIVES</h3>
                         <ul>
                         <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              {% if comment.commenter == request.user  or user.is_superuser %}
                    <a href="{% url 'blog:delete_post' post.id %}"><button style="margin-left:90%;,line-height: .9;color: red;, font-family:Arial;" type="button" name="button">Delete Post</button></a>
                    <a href="{% url 'blog:edit_post' post.id %}"><button style="margin-left:90%;,line-height: .9;color: red;, font-family:Arial;" type="button" name="button">Edit Post</button></a>
              {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        asadsh
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
```

Comment: post the code which is putting out the text. We need something concrete to help you...

Comment: @hansTheFranz I have added the detail.html

Comment: @hansTheFranz That is where the text is being displayed from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add content css files to tinymce, you have to change the tinymce.init object value to include your content_css.

Search for the initialization call in your script and add a line to your object like in this example:

```
tinymce.init({
...
            content_css: [
                '//example.com/js/your-css-here.css'
            ],
...
});
```

If a content_css part is already present, just add the URL to the array, i.e.

```
['url 1 here', 'url 2 here', 'your new url here']
```

In your custom css file, you can now set your desired font size, i.e.

```
body { font-size: 14px; }
```

Comment: I don't understand where the content.css file is. Is it a local file? The one you used in the example is a url.

Comment: The content_css specifies additional CSS files that are to be integrated into the generated code (makes sense e.g. if you have defined some CSS classes you want to use and preview within your editor). Usually that files are stored on a server, but also can be linked relatively. Regarding to my example, the file is stored on a server in the net and uses the same protocol as your editor. You also could specify a relative path, e.g. '/directory/anotherdir/my.css'